# C++11 unordered_set with std::owner_less-like hashing

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, shared-ptr, unordered-map

I'm using external networking library which returns some magic structures representing opened sockets and the docs say that when inserting them into STL containers, they should be compared using `std::owner_less`.

```
std::map<MagicStructure, std::shared_ptr<Client>, std::owner_less<MagicStructure>> sockets;
```

However I'd like to use `unordered_map` instead. How can I do it? `std::owner_less` is a comparator and it's useless for a hash map. Digging in the source code, `MagicStructure` appears to be a typedef for `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: This may be a genuine omission from the standard. We'd need something like `owner_equal` and `owner_hash`; the latter could be the hash of the address of the control block.

Comment: You could look at the source code and see if they set a deleter, and if so what type.  Then try `get_deleter`.  Possibly the `deleter` can be used as a proxy for the "owner".

Comment: good idea, but there is no get_deleter for weak_ptr, it may be extracted and stored separately for sure, but then it might be easier to use your own shared/weak ptr implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that you have to use a `map`, and can't use `unordered_map` for such scenario: http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue1406

> Hash support for the ownership-based equivalence relation cannot be
>   provided by any user-defined manner because information about
>   ownership sharing is not available to users at all. Therefore, the
>   only way to provide ownership-based hash support is to offer it
>   intrusively by the standard library.

In the other words, there is stored (returned by `get()` ) and owned pointer (which is deleted when reference count reaches 0) in a `shared_ptr`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/get/ . For using owned pointer in an `unordered_map`, you need owned pointer based `hash()` and `equals()` operations. But they are not provided in STL. And you can't implement them yourself (without reimplementing `shared_ptr` and changing the definition of your `MagicStructure`) because the owned pointer is not exposed by `shared_ptr` .

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/owner_before is relevant, in that it makes it more clear how `a.get() < b.get()` is different than `a.owner_before(b)`.  A discussion about how two shared pointers can have different `.get()` but a different owner (the "god mode" shared_ptr constructor) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering from `std::owner_less` can be easily adapted into an equality comparison (a and b are equal if neither precedes the other).

<strike>The default hashing implementation for `std::shared_ptr` (hashing the result of `get()`) should be enough.</strike> Not if two pointers to the same object aren't guaranteed to return the same value from `get()`, which is possible in general and plausible in this particular case.

Comment: The hash function seems to be explicitly not compatible with the equality implied by `owner_less`, since the hash is explicitly given as the hash of `get()`!